# How to create a text file from Jenkins TextParameter

Tags: jenkins

I would like to create a text file from TextParameter value in Jenkins job. My parameter value contains multiple lines. I have tried to echo the parameter but only first line is printing.

Comment: Please add more information to such questions. Saves people who want to help annoying guessing. Linux or windows? Example code of your echo? Tried to use echo "<variable>"?

Comment: The text parameter seems bit buggy.. Why not use "File" parameter?

Answer (score 1):

Add build step -> Execute Shell -> echo $PARAMNAMEHERE > file.txt

Comment: "My parameter value contains multiple lines. I have tried to echo the parameter but only first line is printing"

Answer (score 0):

To create a file from Jenkins Job, You need to add a build step call "Execute Shell" and within Shell you need to write following lines

```
#!/bin/bash
echo $PARAMTERNAMEHERE > file.ext
```

This echo statement will echo all the contents to the file.
this works completely if you are using Linux.

Answer (score 0):

Add build step -> Execute NodeJS script:

```
var fs = require('fs');
fs.writeFileSync("file.txt", process.env.**TextParameter**.replace(/\n/g, "\r\n"));
```